# How can I take advantage of the capabilities of a cluster

Tags: distributed-systems, parallel-computing

I'm developing a model in C, and I need to run a couple of simulations (lengthy, and heavy ones). I seem to have a cluster at my disposal, but I'm not very familiar with the concept. I understand that there are different "nodes" ? My program is not designed to take advantage of this individually - it can't event take advantage of multiple processors, because the calculations have to be done in sequence. But I have to run multiple instances of the program, and I was hoping there'd be a way to run them on separate "nodes" (?) to avoid them having to share CPU time too much.

What I know : the cluster runs Red Hat Enterprise Linux for Servers 5.3.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think this may be better suited to [scicomp.SE], but it's also *very* broad. "How to use my super computer" is a big question that,  afaik, has no general answer.

Comment: Ask whoever uses the cluster to guide you along. You might get away with just running a lot of copies of our program in parallel (starting each one with nother seed) and pull results together at the end.

Comment: @vonbrand The original question stated a form of "I don't want to talk to the admin". I agree that this is the proper and maybe only way to go.

Comment: @Raphael, I was really talking about other *users*, not necessarily the *administration*. But you are right.

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience, clusters usually work like this: you submit a job to it (a program), and it allocates a node to run your job. You don't worry about allocating the nodes yourself.

So in your case, simply submit multiple jobs (usually they provide some method to submit batch jobs), and the cluster will allocate different nodes to each of them.

Comment: +1, though the question is only barely appropriate for this site, as Raphael noted in his comment.